# Sound playback not working when using QueueAudio on C++

Tags: c++, audio, sdl-2

I am trying to play a sin wave sound with SDL2 by using the audio queue on C++. In order to do that, I have created a class "Speaker", which has a pushBeep function that is called every time a beep needs to be generated. I have created an AudioDevice successfully, and it is also successful when I do the QueueAudio to the device (I have checked on the debugger) but I can't seem to get any sound out of it.

I have tried changing the way I generate the samples in numerous ways, also, as I said previously, I have checked that the device is properly opened and the QueueAudio returns 0 for success.

This is the class

```cpp
Speaker::Speaker()
{
    SDL_AudioSpec ds;
    ds.freq = Speaker::SPEAKER_FREQUENCY;
    ds.format = AUDIO_F32;
    ds.channels = 1;
    ds.samples = 4096;
    ds.callback = NULL;
    ds.userdata = this;

    SDL_AudioSpec os;
    this->dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &ds, &os, NULL);

    std::cout << "DEVICE: " << this->dev << std::endl;
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(this->dev, 0);
}

Speaker::~Speaker()
{
    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(this->dev);
}

void Speaker::pushBeep(double freq, int duration) {
    int nSamples = duration * Speaker::SPEAKER_FREQUENCY / 1000;
    float* samples = new float[nSamples];
    double v = 0.0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < nSamples; idx++) {
        //float value = (float)Speaker::SPEAKER_AMPLITUDE * std::sin(v * 2 * M_PI / Speaker::SPEAKER_FREQUENCY);
        float value = 440.0;
        samples[idx] = value;
        v += freq;
    }
    int a = SDL_QueueAudio(this->dev, (void*)samples, nSamples * sizeof(float));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    delete[] samples;
    samples = NULL;
}
```

And this is how I call it

```cpp
Speaker s;
s.pushBeep(440.0, 1000);
```

When I try with the sin wave generation code (commented) it gives me a "double to float loss of precision" error. When I use the fixed value (not commented) it does not give the error, but it still does not work.

I expect the program to output the sound.

Comment: What's up with commented line with `sin`? It should be ok (depending on "amplitude" value), constant isn't. Setting constant value is... well let's say not very audible, just one instant loud click and then nothing. Float should peak at 1.0, 440 is too much and most likely will be cut.

Comment: @keltar as I explained on the OP, I also tried the commented line, to no effect, I can't hear anything. But if floats need to be between 0 and 1 then the line is wrong as well, as it creates values way off the limits... on the thousands. I will try this and report. Regarding the length of the sound, I believe it depends on the amount of samples that you place on the queue.

Comment: @dagilpe that's what I said, "depending on amplitude value". Amplitude 1 is fine here. Length was never questionable, I'm saying that constant value isn't even a wave (but we're getting into pedantic grounds of wave definitions - and we shouldn't), it theoretically can only be audible at first sample when value jumps from 0 to your constant, and when it drops back to 0 at the end.

Comment: And it isn't [0;1] but [-1;1] (not that it matters much here, just for clarity, sine wave wraps to negative perfectly).

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things you are missing, or maybe you didn't add to your code snippet. You didn't specify an audio callback so when you call `SDL_QueueAudio();` it didn't know what to do with the data I'm pretty sure. And you weren't calling SDL_PauseAudioDevice() in your example with the delay.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_audio.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace AudioGen
{
const int AMPLITUDE = 1;
const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44000;

// Globals
float *in_buffer;
SDL_atomic_t callback_sample_pos;
SDL_Event event;
SDL_bool running = SDL_TRUE;

/**
 * Structure for holding audio metadata such as frequency
 */
struct AudioData
{
     int sampleNum;
     float frequency;
};

void audio_callback(void *user_data, Uint8 *raw_buffer, int bytes)
{
    float *buffer = (float*)raw_buffer;
    AudioData &audio_data(*static_cast<AudioData*>(user_data));
    int nSamples = bytes / 4; // For F32
    std::cout << nSamples << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < nSamples; i++, audio_data.sampleNum++)
    {
        double time = (double)audio_data.sampleNum / (double)SAMPLE_RATE;
        buffer[i] = (float)(AMPLITUDE * sin(2.0f * M_PI * audio_data.frequency * time));
    }
}

int buffer_length;
void callback(void *user_data, Uint8 *raw_buffer, int bytes)
{
    float *buffer = (float*)raw_buffer;
    int nSamples = bytes/4;
    auto local_sample_pos = SDL_AtomicGet(&callback_sample_pos);
    for(int i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i)
    {
        // Stop running audio if all samples are finished playing
        if(buffer_length == local_sample_pos)
        {
            running = SDL_FALSE;
            break;
        }
        buffer[i] = in_buffer[local_sample_pos];
        ++local_sample_pos;
    }
    SDL_AtomicSet(&callback_sample_pos, local_sample_pos);
}

class Speaker
{
    public:
        Speaker()
        {
            SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
            SDL_AudioSpec ds;
            ds.freq = SAMPLE_RATE;
            ds.format = AUDIO_F32;
            ds.channels = 1;
            ds.samples = 4096;
            ds.callback = callback;
            ds.userdata = &ad; // metadata for frequency

            SDL_AudioSpec os;
            dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &ds, &os, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE);
        }

        ~Speaker()
        {
            SDL_CloseAudioDevice(dev);
            SDL_Quit();
        }
        void pushBeep(float frequency, int duration)
        {
            ad.frequency = frequency; // set the frequency for the beep
            SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
            SDL_Delay(duration); // wait while sound is playing
            SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 1);
        }

        void pushBeep2(float frequency, int duration )
        {
            int nSamples = duration * SAMPLE_RATE / 1000;
            in_buffer = new float[nSamples];
            buffer_length = nSamples;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < nSamples; idx++) {
                double time = (double)idx / (double)SAMPLE_RATE;
                in_buffer[idx] = (float)(AMPLITUDE * std::sin(2.0f * M_PI * frequency * time));
            }
            SDL_QueueAudio(dev, in_buffer, nSamples * sizeof(float));
            SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0);
            while(running){
                while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)!=0);
            }
            delete[] in_buffer;
        }

    private:
        SDL_AudioDeviceID dev;
        AudioData ad;
        int sampleNum = 0;
};
} // End of namespace AudioGen

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AudioGen::Speaker speaker;
    //speaker.pushBeep(440, 1000);
    speaker.pushBeep2(440.0f, 1000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SDL_PauseAudioDevice(this->dev, 0);` starts ("unpauses") the audio playback, and the buffer is supposed to be filling up automatically with silence unless you do otherwise. Yes, the documentation is very poor, I agree, that is why I asked here. The problem with this code is that you need to use a delay, which is what I want to avoid, as it stops the process completely.

Comment: @dagilpe I have updated my example to not use SDL_Delay(). Give it a go and see if it works. Not sure if that is what you want and if it will behave how you want it. And what do you mean by stops the process completely? You mean its a blocking call and you can't run other audio along with it?